# Have a script running regularly in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've been fiddling around with AWS for the past two days, to see what I can do with it and how it would fit my needs. I've already installed LAMP (I installed WAMP on my own computer a long time ago) and R, Rserver & Shiny server.

I was wondering if there is a way to have a script running on a regular basis (every X seconds), and if so, how ?

(In case it's relevant : it's a script I currently have in PHP, but I could translate it in R. It's using curl and it needs to read and write data to a MySQL database.)

Thanks

Comment: Where is this script running? When I do things like this, I just a task scheduler.

Comment: What do you mean by where ? It's currently not running anywhere :) i'm looking for the place to run it

Comment: Then I'm lost with the question. Why can't you run the script on your PC, on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an EC2 instance, you could schedule it using [cron](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/schedule-periodic-tasks-with-cron/).

If you want to use AWS in general, I suggest that you use [Lambda with scheduled events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html).

The first method needs you to have running infrastructure (an EC2 instance), but is easier. The second method has a bit of a learning curve.